# Strong and weak event.NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString* string = @"aSrting";
self.weakString = string;
NSLog(@"string: %@,%p",string,string);
NSLog(@"weakString: %@,%p",self.weakString,self.weakString);}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"weakString: %@,%p",self.weakString,self.weakString);}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"weakString: %@,%p",self.weakString,self.weakString);}
```

Result:

```
2015-11-08 18:17:06.022 HZStrongWeakTest[4514:370204] string: aSrting,0x101b33088
2015-11-08 18:17:06.023 HZStrongWeakTest[4514:370204] weakString: aSrting,0x101b33088
2015-11-08 18:17:06.023 HZStrongWeakTest[4514:370204] weakString: aSrting,0x101b33088
2015-11-08 18:17:06.026 HZStrongWeakTest[4514:370204] weakString: aSrting,0x101b33088
```

Q: the 'aString' isn't release. 'weakString' isn't hold the object.
   how do it work?

Comment: How is `weakString` defined?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, weak) NSString* weakString;  //define

Comment: //@interface ViewController ()//@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString* weakString;
//@end

Comment: See "NSString literals memory management" to figure it out